# Transform $x^{\sin(x)}$ to expression with constant exponent?

Tags: real-analysis, computer-algebra-systems

I am working on an exercice which asks to convert expressions into those basic blocs :

- Standard operations ($+$, $-$, $*$, $/$)
- $\exp$
- $\ln$
- $\sin$
- $\cos$
- powers (as long as the exposant is constant)

I have an issue with this expression :
$$\\X^{\sin(X)}$$

By developing sine, I get that :
$$X^{\frac{\exp(iX) - \exp(-iX)}{2i}}$$

I don't see at all how the exponent could be constant here?
Is there some way to write this expression to get a constant exponent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{\sin x} = \exp(\sin x\ln x).$$
Motivation:
$$x^{\sin x} = \exp(\ln(x^{\sin x})).$$

Comment: Thank you, but how do you get from my "development" to your expression ? What formula do you use ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise, see my edit.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise you're going the wrong way in your development... it won't get you anywhere, you just went into complex numbers and made your life harder.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Thank you so much! But, how do you get from your second expression to your first expression ?

Comment: @orion Yup ! Sometimes, unfortunately, the first thing that comes to my mind isn't the easiest one :(